# How to solve this keyerror?

Tags: python, json, keyerror

```
        header = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        url = 'https://tk9k0fkvyj.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/default/top20-predictor'
 
        # make POST request and load response
        r = requests.post(url, params=input_json, headers=header).json()['body']
        result = json.loads(r)
 
        # render the html template sending the variables
        return render_template("score.html", score=result['score'], proba=result['proba'])
 
KeyError: 'body'
```

Please let me know the correct code for this or how to deubg..

Comment: Are you sure, the `data` be send as `params` and not `data` ? Try `requests.post(url, data=input_json, headers=header).json()['body']`, assuming `input_json` is json encoded

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
r = requests.post(url, params=input_json, headers=header).json()['body']
```

use only

```
r = requests.post(url, params=input_json, headers=header).json()
```

you are getting error coz there is no any "body" key in r...